# Collision between things in lists XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm making a zombie survival game and I use classes and lists to create both the players bullets and the zombies, but I can't figure out how to check for collisions between them.
Both the zombies and the bullets are created using classes.

Declaring the lists

```
    List<Bullets> bullets = new List<Bullets>();
    List<Zombies> zombies = new List<Zombies>();
```

Running in update

```
for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        {
            bullets[i].Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)bullets[i].position.X,             (int)bullets[i].position.Y, bullets[i].texture.Width, bullets[i].texture.Height);
            if (!bullets[i].isVisible)
            {
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each instance of bullet and each instance of zombie needs to be assigned a collision model, i.e. a rectangle or circle which is assigned to each instance and can identify intersections between one rectangle, the other way is to compare the x y or z coordinates to that of the x y z coordinates of another body. Collision detection is a huge subject that is addressed very commonly in XNA and about 1million other searches on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest, if you want to see whether two rectangles are colliding with each other, you can use

[Rectangle.Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx)

So just loop through all the bullets and all the zombies and see if any of them intersect. There you have a collision.

Of course you can then get better performance by reducing comparisons, such as using a quadtree to prevent needing to check for collisions by entities which are ages away, but two loops will go fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the bullets rectangles collide with each other.
see: [Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx)

So first you'll need to give your zombie and bullets a rectangle.
(you maybe want to do this in your self created zombie and bullets classes)

Then make a loop and check for the bullets in the list if there is a collision.

like this:

```
foreach (Zombies z in zombies)
{
    foreach (Bullets b in bullets)
    {
        if (b.rectangle.Intersects(z.rectangle))
        {           
            // so your loop can delete the bullet                   
            b.isVisible = false;
            // do something with the zombie
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As also you can use [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) to optimise loops.

Comment: An Octree is for 3D space, for 2D space prefer to use [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) :)